# Multiple mssql connections in express REST API

Tags: sql-server, node.js, api, express, routes

I've made up a express server with a few routes. The plan was to give each route its own mssql connection via connection pooling, but it appears the module can only have one global connection. Am I doing something wrong here or is this intended?

Also, should I even do this if possible? Should I have one API per database? All of these database are on one engine and are seperate schemas.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is here. You say, firstly, that you plan to give "*each route its own mssql*", are you saying you'll be hosting multiple SQL Server instances, and each route uses a different instance? But you then go on to say that the databases are all on one data engine, but different schemas..? A Schema is an object within a database, not the other way around. A database doesn't belong to a schema, a schema belongs to a database. This is how 3 part naming convention works `[database].[schema].[object]`. I.e.`AdventureWorks.sales.Customers`; `sales` is the schema.

Comment: Yeah, like I said they are all on the same engine/server, different schemas. I've tried fully qualifying the queries but no luck.

Comment: yes, I can kinda see what you're getting at. I appreciate that English is not your first language, which means that your sentences can be interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, super helpful. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The module allows you to set up connection pools which act as connections to databases as users. So if you want to connect to a different database, you have to use a different pool. For example:

```
const config1 = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'server1',
    database: 'database1',
    options: {
        // ...
    }
}
const config2 = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'server1',
    database: 'database2'
    // ...
}

const pool1 = new sql.ConnectionPool(conf1, err => {
    // ...
})
const pool2 = new sql.ConnectionPool(conf2, err => {
    // ...
})
```

Now when you want to access `database1`, you use `pool1`, and so on. For more info, [refer to the mssql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connection-pools). The theme here, though, is that if you want to access different databases, *you must use different connection pools*. Also be careful how you use the word "schema" around SQL Server. Schema in the general context of SQL refers to the structure of a database or table, but in Microsoft's SQL Server it can also refer to a feature that allows you to namespace tables inside a database for management, ownership and security purposes. See [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx) for a better explanation. As Larnu said in the comments, the hierarchy goes `[database].[schema].[table]`. Since connection pools access databases, you don't need to specify that bit – you can stick to `[schema].[table]` or even omit the schema depending on your setup.

Now as to whether you *should* separate out the pools, well obviously you have to if you're using more than one database. Otherwise, if it's the same database, I think we'd need more context and even then it's not black and white.

Just keep in mind, the connection pool is a *user* logging in to a *database* – it has the same privileges as that user. So do you want `RouteA` to only have access to certain database objects and ensure this is enforced database-side? Then set up a database user (`RouteAUser`), set up a connection pool for that route (`PoolA`), and inside that pool's config, use the `RouteAUser`'s credentials, and so on. If all your data access is written inside the application, hidden from the end user, you probably don't need to do this –  just write `RouteA`'s code so that it only accesses the objects you want.

Answer (score 0):

> What if the two databases need to be queried together?

The mssql package allows you to access different databases using the table qualifier.

```
const result1 = pool.request().query("select * from DATABASE1..table1 t JOIN DATABASE2..table1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id")
```